# How to make a clean animation Python

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```py
import itertools
import sys
import time
import threading

done = False
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(f'\rSome animation ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

def somecode():
    global done
    t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
    t.start()
    # Some code
    done = True

somecode()
```

And it looks like this:
[image: Animation]

My question is how to remove the white bar because it would look better without the bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably an artifact of your shell/terminal emulator

Comment: In Tilix running ZSH I don't even see it animate.  What OS are you on and what terminal are you running in?

Comment: I am on Windows and I compilied it with pyinstaller for example.Note: Remove the ```done = True``` to see it animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you print `\033[?25l` ASCII character before the `for` loop which hides the cursor. Also, you can use `\033[?25h` to back the cursor to the visible state.

Answer (score 1):

you can use os package as follow:

```
import itertools
import sys
import time
import threading
import os

os.system('setterm -cursor off')

done = False
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            os.system('setterm -cursor on')
            break
        sys.stdout.write(f'\rSome animation ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

def somecode():
    global done
    t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
    t.start()
    # Some code
    done = True

somecode()
```

Comment: This implementation will not work on Windows (which the OP is using) as `setterm` is a Linux terminal utility.